# how much minimum memory required to run .NET Binary on Linux platform using Mono

Tags: .net, linux, mono

I have Linux PC with Ubuntu 12.04 and mono 2.8.10.

I want to run one .NET standalone GUI based application on my Linux PC using Mono.

How much minimum memory required to run .NET binary using mono and is there any limitation  regarding memory to run .NET application using mono on Linux Platform?

I have also faced problem like that My free memory goes decreased continuously in terms of 100 MB whenever any operation did on GUI which is running using mono.

Is there any one have idea regarding memory consumption for mono in Linux?

Comment: Mono has a garbage collector. Some versions of it might use as much as memory as available. So don't worry that much about remaining free memory. Read also http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: But, whenever i run my .NET binary using mono then at that time it consumes memory around 100MB bunch and does not frees that amount of memory after closing the application.

Comment: cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3940772 kB
MemFree:          254344 kB

Comment: whenever i run my .NET binary using mono then after sometime my memory goes down drastically up to 300MB free memory from 3 GB memory and i have also checked in the code that it uses all the handler mechanism of GC (Garbage Collector) properly. But still it causes memory leak issue continuously. Please help me if any one have idea regarding this issue.

Comment: Just don't worry. Worry only if swapping is too high, or if Mono runtime system tells you about too much memory used. See [Mono Performance Tips](http://www.mono-project.com/Performance_Tips) etc. Show your Mono code if you want more help.

Comment: One More thing that whenever i minimized the GUI window and again maximized that window which is running under mono, Then some of the GUI part will be hanged and can not be refreshed properly. DO you have any idea about Property Grid control support in mono?

Comment: How much memory does mono consumes by default after running simple GUI .NET application using mono?

Comment: I have run my .NEt application using mono and observed that at the end of the my free memory goes from 2 GB to 300 MB. I have also checked and verified my own USB driver which is not going to leak any memory. I have also verified from application that it doesn't leak any more memory. so it seems like that mono consumes that much amount of memory. I have also observed that after closing that binary and unloading my USB driver, still memory is not going to be free. Does any one have idea or clue about this issue?

Comment: Please reply me if any one have faced this type of issue.

Comment: does any one have idea about how to reduce memory consumption which is consumed by mono?